# PHP Treating a header content-type wth AJAX success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a function in PHP that returns the following

```
...
header("Content-Type: {$result2['ContentType']}");
    echo $result2['ContentType'];
```

I call that PHP function using JQUERY AJAX, as =>

```
.. success: function(result){
                window.location.href = result.location;
     
                     }});
```

And with the successful result, it should redirect the user to that. But this seems to not catch the redirect from the PHP.

Thanks

Comment: Well, PHP is sending a redirect.  And I wouldn't expect AJAX calls to respond to an actual redirect.  What the PHP code is doing is echoing the value in `$result2['ContentType']`.  What is that value?  When you debug in your browser, what does `result` contain?

Comment: How is `echo $result2['ContentType'];` connected to `result.location`?

Comment: @El_Vanja ``echo $result2['ContentType']; comes from an S3 Object using the getObject. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/download-objects.html

Comment: It is an object from AWS using the S3 @David

Comment: @pullhyphoonprotocol: Ok, but what *is* it?  When you debug in the browser, what does it contain?  If you `console.log(result)` in the `success` callback, what gets logged to the console?  Don't make assumptions, debug and observe.

Comment: If it's a whole object, what is the purpose of setting it as the content type?

Comment: I got a ``application/octet-stream`` @David

Comment: @pullhyphoonprotocol: Well, `application/octet-stream` isn't really a valid URL.  What are you expecting to redirect the user to and why?

Comment: I am using that to make a user able to download an object from S3 using PHP SDK. This are the official docs from AWS -> SDK -> PHP. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/download-objects.html

Comment: So `result.location` is undefined, because you're trying to access the `location` property on a string.